# Does a PageAsyncTask fire off its own thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, pageasynctask

Does a PageAsyncTask  fire off its own thread when used in a .aspx page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will. In order for something to run asynchronous it has to run on a different thread.

For a more in-depth explanation on the usage of PageAsyncTask check out

http://www.w3enterprises.com/articles/asynchronous.aspx

> In order for PageAsyncTask to work at you should include the string "Async=True" in your ASPX's page's @Page directive. You can also control the timeout for the asychronous task with the "AsyncTimeout=x" parameter where the value for "x" should be in seconds.